# Should I say "I" in a paper, as the sole author?

Tags: publications, writing

I am the sole author of a paper which I would like to publish in a journal.

Is it better to use "I" for example "In this paper, I present xyz"

Or is better to avoid "I" like "In this paper, xyz is presented"

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: even with a single authored papers, you should normally use "**we**", *not* "I".

> "In this paper we present a very interesting theory of everything. We
> do this by invoking the idea of...".